# Why would Excel 2013 data validation cell range change after upgrading from 2007?

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2013

We have an Excel file made in Excel 2007 that uses Data Validation (List) to generate a drop-down list from a range of cells on a different sheet:

[image]

When opening the file in Excel 2013, the drop-down box is empty because the cell range has been changed to `B98:B101`, where the data is located in cells `B62:B65` on the 'Lookup Tables' sheet. Opening in Excel 2007 (on a non-upgraded workstation), the drop-down list is showing correctly, with the correct cell range, but in 2013, the cell range has shifted 36 rows down. Any idea why this would be and should I be worried that other formulas/lookups in the file may have also shifted?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was explored extensively here:

http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=150080

Per the final posting on this thread this can be resolved by downloading the MS Office Compatibility pack. Regards,

Comment: looks like that thread is about opening a new file in an older version. I am attempting to open a file made in 2007 with 2013, so the Compatibility Pack would not be relevant.

Comment: Would it not make sense to try anyways as it refers to compatibility issues between Office 2007 and 2013 on how they handle drop-down validation lists? You don't think this seems relevant to your issue even if its not the exact situation the posting is discussing?

Comment: does not make sense, at this time, to send the IT crew abuzz for a goose egg with description worded exactly opposite of my situation. it may come to that tho